# reading each line of text is still performing each line despite my attempted condition

Tags: c#, foreach, textbox, line

I'm reading each line of text, and if it contains certain text I warn.  Down where `warningsTextBox.Text +=`  and has new lines and a bullet point, it is inserting the newline/bullet points even if the conditions are not met so I end up with some bulleted/blank lines along with my warnings.  I figured where I put

```
if ((bomInputTextBox.Text.Contains(s4) && (bomInputTextBox.Text.Contains(s5))))
```

it would stop this from happening, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"t:\\DESIGNER\\customcheck", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(fileStream)) {
        while ((lineOfText = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            Regex regex4 = new Regex("<ifcontainsand>(.*)</ifcontainsand>");
            var v4 = regex4.Match(lineOfText);
            string s4 = v4.Groups[1].ToString().ToUpper();

            Regex regexContainsAnd = new Regex("<ifcontainsand2>(.*)</ifcontainsand2>");
            var v5 = regexContainsAnd.Match(lineOfText);
            string s5 = v5.Groups[1].ToString().ToUpper();

            Regex regex6 = new Regex("<ifcontainsandWarningText>(.*)</ifcontainsandWarningText>");
            var v6 = regex6.Match(lineOfText);
            string s6 = v6.Groups[1].ToString().ToUpper();

            if ((bomInputTextBox.Text.Contains(s4) && (bomInputTextBox.Text.Contains(s5)))) {
                 warningsTextBox.Text +=
                     (Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "•" + s6).ToString();
            }
```

Comment: The reason the code is like this is because I'm letting other people generate their own "if else" statements that the program grabs externally from a config file without recompiling.  Otherwise I wouldn't have all the added regex steps.

Comment: Please take a pen and write "I will never use regular expressions to parse XML/HTML" 1000 times....

Comment: It's not even xml, it's my own text file where people can add their own statements such as if the material list contains 23" rack equipemnt and a 19" rach, it would warn about incompatibility.  I hardcode lots of information but now i've made it so they can enter it themselves using a GUI.  it's not clear, but I'm setting it and forgetting it.  It works great already other than the extra lines :(

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you never actually check to see whether any of your regex-matches were successful. When a regex-match is *not* successful, all capture-groups are the empty string `""`; so whenever you process a `lineOfText` that lacks `<ifcontainsand>(.*)</ifcontainsand>` and `<ifcontainsand2>(.*)</ifcontainsand2>`, your `if` condition is `true` (since *all* strings contain the empty string).

To check whether a match succeeded, you can use [the `Match.Success` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success.aspx):

```
if (v4.Success && bomInputTextBox.Text.Contains(s4)
    && v5.Success && bomInputTextBox.Text.Contains(s5)) {
```